# Como posso pegar o valor de um text e imprimir na tela

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando imprimir um valor que foi digitado por usuario a partir de um `textfield`, por exemplo um campo nome.

Mas depois de obte-lo, quero imprimir o tal nome.

Comment: Imprimir um valor onde? Console? Alert? Outro input field? Tente formular melhor a sua pergunta. Se possível, coloque parte do seu código que está com dúvida.

Comment: por `imprimir` vc pode usar um `alert('')` ou colocar o valor dentro de um elemento html (como um text). Você também pode imprimir no console (usado pra desenvolvimento)

Answer (score 3):

Para obteres o valor digitado, tanto podes fazer por `javascript` como `jquery`.

Tendo a input:

```
<input type="text" id="inputValor" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('inputValor').value;
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#inputValor').val()
```

Por ambos os exemplos consegues obter o texto digitado na input.
Deixo JSFiddle com exemplo completo para veres:

[Exemplo Valor Input - **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/jCt4t/)

Answer (score 3):

Considerando que o ID do elemento textfield seja **id1**:

HTML:

```
<input id="id1" type="text"/>
```

Javascript:

```
//Obtem o valor do elemento textfield e armazena na variável "valor"
var valor = document.getElementById('id1').value;

//Para imprimir na página
document.write(valor);

//Para imprimir em um elemento específico
document.getElementById('IdDoElementoEspecifico').innerText = valor

//Para imprimir em um Input Text
document.getElementById('IdDoElementoInputText').value = valor;
```